# Why is there no rat's nest in this file? (KiCad)

Tags: kicad

Can anyone tell me anything about this schematic that might cause it *not* to have a rat's nest?  By the default settings, most pins are warnings.

This is simply a bus for some buttons on a pull down resistor....
[image]

I could do the breadboard manually, but what I'm really interested in is the cause of this error!  I import the net.. no rat's nest.

Comment: The "no rat's nest" error is something new to me. Perhaps you forgot to associate a footprint to each component using cvpcb?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kicad, but my guess would be that the little diamonds on each device terminal imply that there's no real connection there, despite the close proximity of the green lines. Perhaps either the devices or the lines are slightly "off grid".

Comment: Perhaps it was drawn using graphical lines rather than wires - KiCad won't see the lines as electrical connections.

Comment: What does DRC tell you?

Comment: Design rules check shows: nothing. However.... ERC shows "Conflict Problem Between Pins." The pin type is unspecified, does that change anything?  It just says