# KiCad - what does this syntax Highlighitng mean, why can't connections be made?

Tags: pcb-design, kicad

[image]

Everything turns yellow and it won't let me make ANY connections in Pcbnew.

Does anyone know why this is?  Also, when I import the netlist, there are no rat's nest!

This is the diagram, but I was trying to do this manually because, well no rats nest...
see [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124239/why-is-there-no-rats-nest-in-this-file-kicad).

Comment: My guess would be that you aren't on the copper layer, confirm by checking the dropdown for your current working layer.

Comment: As for the rats nest, there's a button on the left that turns it on and off.

Comment: That button to the left makes no difference.  I am on the Copper layer, same behavior from front and back layer.  The footprints are Custom.

Comment: Did you make a schematic from the netlist first? Some circuit design programs require that you have a schematic first, and then switch to the PCB.

Comment: I had some weird problems with the ratsnest being gone in the begining. Choosing "Rebuild Board Connectivity" from "Tools" -> "Netlist" menu helped me.

Comment: If you highlight a not connected pin, all non connected pins will light up, which is your case. You should create a schematics first, like derstrom8 said.